# Query gallery thumbnail returns cursor with 0 count

Tags: android, android-gallery

I would like to get the thumbnail image paths of the gallery images.
So, I'm preparing a query and asking cursor for data which will look like this.

`Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;`
`String columns[] = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};`
`String where = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID+ " = "+ info.id;`
`Cursor imagecursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, columns,where , null, null);
 imagecursor.moveToPosition(0);`

In the above code the imageCursor is having count 0.

If I query the same thumbnail id(which is used in above code) it is returning bitmap.

`MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(context.getContentResolver(), info.id,
                        Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be the where clause, try not using it to see if it returns something, also try to do this:

```
String where = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID+ " =?"
String[] replace = { info.id };
Cursor imagecursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, columns,where , replace, null);
```

Comment: glad I was helpful, mark the answer as correct so that other people with the same problem can see it :)

Comment: edit : Its a type actually , It is not working with the above code snippet also..